# MVC Controller background operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing a webpage that getting a argument from query-string. This webpage only insert this argument into DB. Nothing more.

The user getting getting empty document back. Like this:

```
public ActionResult Track(string q)
{
    // Insert to DB.

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

What I want to do is to return the empty-document as soon as possible. I'm mean that without waiting to DB insert. I'm thinking about Run a background task like:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dowork());
```

Is this good practice?

What about performance, if we are assuming that this webpage will get 1000 requests per seconds?

Comment: Why would the performance be so different versus doing the work before returning an empty result? Either way you're doing the same amount of work.

Comment: Bad practice. Search for "fire and forget ASP.Net" and "long running operations in ASP.Net"... If your operation takes reasonable time - use proper `async`/`awiat` server side and fire and forget from browser/client instead, if it takes long time - use some external scheduling/queuing solution.

Comment: Returning empty document is very quick. This is the low bound. fixed time. Inserting DB records into DB is can be changed from time to time. Depends on requests rate. If I'm getting alot of request at same time, I'm can give answer to the client and doing my work on the next seconds, which may be much more quite...

Comment: You could just use ajax to send the request from the browser.

Comment: Already doing this. Thanks for tip.

Comment: Async does *not* return the response any quicker than sync. This is an all too common misconception. All async does is return the thread to the worker pool to field other requests until the intended work is done. At which point, the thread is returned to finish returning the response or whatever. In other words, it doesn't block the thread while the processing is going on. If anything, async might actually be *slower* since it has more overhead than sync. Anything you do inside your action, async or not *must* complete before the response will be returned to the user.